# How to list all databases whose column from a specific table has a specific type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to list all databases with a specific name and whose column from a specific table has a specific type like DATE

To get all databases with a specific name :

```
SELECT [name] FROM [sysdatabases] WHERE [name] like 'myDBname_%'
```

To get a specific type for all columns :

```
select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from myDBname_something.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'A_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME'
```

How can I link these two requests ?
In other words, how can I get the result of my second request for each result of the first request ?

Comment: A database does not have columns. A database has tables, tables have columns. Are you conflating Table with Database?

Comment: You need cursor + dynamic sql (`sp_executesql`) to generate your second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your second query as the parameter in the system proc, `sp_MSforeachdb`

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = ''A_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME'' '
```

If you want to filter for only certain databases, you can add an additional filter on the TABLE_CATALOG column to the second query.   The TABLE_CATALOG is the database name.

If you want to make sure you don't get any empty results from databases that don't have any columns that meet the filter, you can put an IF EXISTS() before your query:

```
    EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * from [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = ''A_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME'')
      select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = ''A_SPECIFIC_TABLE_NAME'' '
```

Comment: When I run your request I got 222 rows out of 43 qualified databases. I have a bunch of lines with TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE all empty

Comment: How to remove from the result databases whose filter returns nothing ?

Comment: Ah!   To do that you would use an IF EXISTS() with your SELECT in it  before the SELECT, so that the SELECT only happens if it will return results for that database.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option that doesn't use any loops or cursors. I am using sys.database to generate a single select statement. Unless you have a LOT of databases this isn't going to be much, if any, performance boost over a loop based solution. But I really dislike cursors and loops and this is a fairly simple way to build dynamic sql to avoid using a loop.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' --need to initialize to empty string
    , @TableToFind sysname = 'YourTableName'

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'select TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from [' + db.name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  where TABLE_NAME = @TableToFind UNION ALL '
FROM sys.databases db
WHERE [state] = 0 --only gets online multi user databases
    AND name LIKE 'myDBname_%'

IF LEN(@SQL) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10)

    SELECT @SQL
    --uncomment the line below when you are comfortable the dynamic sql generated will function.
    --EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TableToFind sysname', @TableToFind = @TableToFind
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic sql in a loop to fetch DB Names or use dynamic sql with cursor

Method 1: Using Loop

```
Declare @ssql nvarchar(max),@DBName varchar(100),@rowcount int,@datatype varchar(10)

Create table #temp(id int identity(1,1) ,DBName varchar(100))

set @rowcount=0
set @datatype='int'

Insert into #temp(DBName)
SELECT [name]  FROM sys.[sysdatabases] WHERE [name] like 'MyDBName%'

while @rowcount<=1
begin

select @DBName=DBName from #temp where id=@rowcount

set @ssql=N'select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from '+@DBName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME in (select TABLE_NAME from '+@DBName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'')
and DATA_TYPE='''+@datatype+''''

--select @ssql
exec sp_executesql @ssql

set @rowcount=@rowcount+1
end
```

Method 2: Cursor

```
    Declare @ssql nvarchar(max),@DBName varchar(100),@rowcount int,@datatype varchar(10)
set @rowcount=0
set @datatype='int'
DECLARE cursorDBName CURSOR -- Declare cursor
FOR

SELECT [name]  FROM sys.[sysdatabases] WHERE [name] like 'MyDBName%'
OPEN cursorDBName -- open the cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDBName

 INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

 set @ssql=N'select TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from '+@DBName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME in (select TABLE_NAME from '+@DBName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE=''BASE TABLE'')
and DATA_TYPE='''+@datatype+''''

--select @ssql
exec sp_executesql @ssql

 FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDBName

   INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE cursorDBName -- close the cursor

DEALLOCATE cursorDBName
```